# Callback in Free Pascal from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, callback, freepascal

There are declarations in proprietary DLL header:

```
class CJDummyClass
{
};
typedef CJDummyClass * J_IMG_CALLBACK_OBJECT;
#ifdef __BORLANDC__
  typedef void (__stdcall*J_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)(J_tIMAGE_INFO * pAqImageInfo);
#else
  typedef void (CJDummyClass::*J_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)(J_tIMAGE_INFO * pAqImageInfo);
#endif
```

Also there is an exported function to link callback function to DLL, and then it is possible to process some data placed in memory by pointer pAqImageInfo

I'm writing application using this DLL in FreePascal, almost everything I need successfully translated, dynamically linked and wrapped into a class, but now I have problem with callback function.
Here is part of my code:

```
interface
type
  pJ_tIMAGE_INFO = ^J_tIMAGE_INFO;
  TJ_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION = procedure( const pAqImageInfo: pJ_tIMAGE_INFO ) of object; cdecl;
  PJ_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION = ^TJ_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION;

  TJaiFactory = class( TObject )
  .....
    procedure ImageCallback( const pAqImageInfo: pJ_tIMAGE_INFO ); cdecl;
  .....
  end;
implementation
procedure TJaiFactory.ImageCallback(pAqImageInfo: pJ_tIMAGE_INFO); cdecl;
begin
  // some data processing here
end;
```

Insidy my ImageCallback I got pAqImageInfo = nil instead of some actual pointer. I suspect that I have to define type or parameters for callback some other way, but I don't know how.

First question: if in C++ there is a void function then as far as I understand it is procedure in terms of Pascal and it should be defined as procedure or as function with some pointer result (but without actual result)?

Second question: if function declared in C++ as member of class, what is correct way to translate type of this function into Pascal? I'm not sure what is going on with "this" pointer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. procedure is equivalent to void function in C/C++.
2. In Visual C++, `this` pointer is passed in `ecx` register and default calling convention for member function is equivalent to `__stdcall` except when you passed variadic argument, it will changes to `__cdecl`. Your callback should be correctly except calling convention.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand about calling convention for member function. How should I declare it in Pascal? Should I declare something or provide something to make callback correct? I'm not sure but it looks like nil in pointer is nil for "this". I tried stdcall too and result was same - nil in pointer.

Comment: Is DLL is x86? And what is compiler that DLL is using? Is calling convention for member function in Free Pascal is the same as Delphi? I don't known much about Free Pascal. But, in Delphi, the first argument is passed in `edx` register.

Comment: DLL is x86, Free Pascal compiler is x86 too, and in delphi-compatible mode (when it was in default objfpc mode the callback function wasn't linked at all).

Comment: Check your proprietary DLL what is compiler it used. If Visual C++, `procedure ImageCallback(pAqImageInfo: pJ_tIMAGE_INFO); stdcall;` should be working. DON'T make `ImageCallback` as member function. If you do that, Free Pascal will assign `pAqImageInfo` to `edx` register instead the variable that VC++ passed in the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was sure that I checked this combination but... now it comes that I didn't. Or it was when I used objfpc mode instead of delphi-compatible. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. A  *bla()   is equivalent to bla(). IOW a function TYPE is implicitely a pointer in Pascal.
2. A C++ class can't be represented in a different compiler. Even two C++ compilers will have possibly differing representations.
3. as a result of (2), the function type is not OF OBJECT. It is not a Pascal class. OF OBJECT will make the function type a two pointer type (instance + address), afaik a concept that C++ doesn't have.

So

```
 Type
    J_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION = procedure (pAqImageInfo:Pointer); StdCall; 
 // or cdecl depending on compiler
```

is a reasonable approximation.